# Unity3d: Position a gameobject such that its forms a right angled triangle with other two gameobjects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, position, angle

[image]

How do I position `C gameObject` such that it forms a right angled triangle with `A and B`. I tried to use `(B.transform.position.x,A.transform.position.z)` but it still gives me something which is close to `A` (it takes it globally). I want the `C` to be along the `local red axis of A` and `local green axis of B` as seen in the picture. What do I do?

Comment: I missed the last part of the question of the local axis's, to solve that specifically you have to directions, you just need to calculate the intersection of the 2 directions typically with the cross product.

Comment: This should help: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/3d_Math_functions

Comment: So is it ` Vector3.Cross(A.transform.right, -B.transform.up)`?

Comment: at that link there is a section for LineLineIntersection, which you should be able to use with A.transform.right, and -b.transform.up and their positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways of expressing this problem.

---

One is finding such a point along B's up axis such that it makes a right angle with A. This would ignore any rotations of A.

To do this, project A's position along B's up. In other words, find the dot product of (A-B) and B's up, multiply that by B's up, and add that to B.

```
Vector3 cPos = B.transform.position + Vector3.Dot(A.transform.position - B.transform.position, B.transform.up) * B.transform.up;
C.transform.position = cPos;
```

---

Another way would be finding the intersection point of B's up and A's right. This would possibly make non right angles or maybe no point at all depending on the rotations of A and B.

This is a bit more complicated, and [the link in the comments](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/3d_Math_functions) has a good implementation:

> ```
> public static bool LineLineIntersection(out Vector3 intersection, Vector3 linePoint1, Vector3 lineVec1, Vector3 linePoint2, Vector3 lineVec2){
>
>       Vector3 lineVec3 = linePoint2 - linePoint1;
>       Vector3 crossVec1and2 = Vector3.Cross(lineVec1, lineVec2);
>       Vector3 crossVec3and2 = Vector3.Cross(lineVec3, lineVec2);
>
>       float planarFactor = Vector3.Dot(lineVec3, crossVec1and2);
>
>       //is coplanar, and not parrallel
>       if(Mathf.Abs(planarFactor) < 0.0001f && crossVec1and2.sqrMagnitude > 0.0001f)
>       {
>           float s = Vector3.Dot(crossVec3and2, crossVec1and2) / crossVec1and2.sqrMagnitude;
>           intersection = linePoint1 + (lineVec1 * s);
>           return true;
>       }
>       else
>       {
>           intersection = Vector3.zero;
>           return false;
>       }
>   }
> ```

Then to find your position:

```
Vector3 cPos;
bool doIntersect = LineLineIntersection(out cPos, A.transform.position, A.transform.right, B.transform.position, B.transform.up);
if (doIntersect) {
    C.transform.position = cPos;
} else {
    // do something reasonable, like using projection, or not changing the position
    Vector3 cPos = B.transform.position + Vector3.Dot(A.transform.position - B.transform.position, B.transform.up) * B.transform.up;
    C.transform.position = cPos;
}
```